# std::sort not sorting vector properly

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, comparison, stdvector

I want to sort my vector of pairs by the ratio of the first to the second value of the pair. I am using C++ STL `sort` function but, I don't know, It is not sorting the vector properly here is my code:

**comparator**

```
bool comparator(const std::pair<int, int> &item1, const std::pair<int, int> &item2)
{
    return (item1.first / item1.second) < (item2.first / item2.second);
}
```

**sort function call**

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> items = {{4, 5}, {1, 4}, {3, 5}, {6, 7}, {8, 8}};
    std::sort(items.begin(), items.end(), comparator);
    for (auto item : items)
        std::cout << item.first << ", " << item.second << "\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

**my output**

```
8, 8
4, 5
1, 4
3, 5
6, 7
```

**expected output**

```
8, 8
6, 7
4, 5
3, 5
1, 4
```

I also tried

```
return (double)(item1.first / item1.second) > (double)(item2.first / item2.second);
```

but it is also giving me another output

```
4, 5
1, 4
3, 5
6, 7
8, 8
```

Comment: Your comparator is doing integer divisions, which produce an `int` with rounding toward zero. That probably explains your concern. (It's also possible - although I haven't checked - that it doesn't meet the mandatory requirement of a comparator to define a strict-weak ordering - which would cause undefined behaviour). In any event, to avoid the concern with integer division, try `return item1.first*item2.second < item2.first*item1.second` which is mathematically equivalent except for effects of integer division (although there is potential for integer overflow, depending on values provided)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to compare float results like

```
 return (static_cast<double>( item1.first ) / item1.second) < 
        (static_cast<double>( item2.first ) / item2.second);
```

In this case the vector will be sorted in the ascending order and the result will be

```
1, 4
3, 5
4, 5
6, 7
8, 8
```

If you want to sort the vector in the descending order then use this return statement

```
return (static_cast<double>( item2.first ) / item2.second) < 
        (static_cast<double>( item1.first ) / item1.second);
```

In this case the output will be

```
8, 8
6, 7
4, 5
3, 5
1, 4
```

As for this return statement

```
return (double)(item1.first / item1.second) > (double)(item2.first / item2.second);
```

then in parentheses there is used the integer arithmetic

```
(item1.first / item1.second)
```

So casting to double has no effect for the comparison.

Comment: I have a question I tried  ` return (double)(item1.first / item1.second) < (double)(item2.first / item2.second);`, But why it does not worked? also, why it didn't type-casted?

Comment: @SidharthMudgil It does not work because in the   parentheses (item1.first / item1.second) there is used the integer arithmetic.

Comment: Another option is to replace `/` with `*` (to avoid floating-point arithmetic).